# Error using 'free' on char array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, free

I'm new to C and trying to write a command line program with it. I'm trying to free a char array right before the program terminates. But I'm getting a "debug assertion failed" run-time error when it reaches the `free` command. Before it reaches that point, the program is removing characters in that array up until the first whitespace. I'm using the incrementing technique on the array since I read that was a way to remove chars one by one from an array. Here's that piece of code:

```
char command[140];
char * input = getInput();  //prompt function for user input

//get string up to first whitespace to separate the command and its parameters
for (i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++)
{
    if (input[i] == ' ' || input[i] == '\0')
        break;

    command[i] = input[i];
}

for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)    //removes command and space and leaves parameters
    input++;

command[i] = '\0';  //null terminate char array
numParams = getNumParams(input);
free(input);  //should've added this line earlier to avoid confusion.
```

My `getInput()` function does this:

```
char * getInput()
{
    int n, size = 260;
    char * input = (char*)malloc(size);
    if (!input)                 //make sure memory allocation worked
        return NULL;

    do
    {
        printf("cmd> ");            //prompt
        fgets(input, 256, stdin);   //get user input/commands
        n = strlen(input);
    } while (n <= 1);

    if (input[n - 1] == '\n')           //remove new line from input array
        input[n - 1] = '\0';

    return input;
}
```

So after the rest of the program ends I want to be able to free the memory that was allocated in the `getInput()` function. I'm thinking the way I have the `input` returning to a char pointer is messing that up. But I'm not sure how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: And where do you call `free`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't posted the line that calls `free`. I am assuming that you are calling:

```
free(input);
```

I can see why that would be a problem.

You are changing the value of `input` in the lines:

```
for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) 
    input++;
```

When you call `free`, the value of the pointer must be what was returned by `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`. If you use any other pointer value, the program is subject to undefined behavior.

Make sure that you keep the value that was returned, so you can call `free` using it.

```
char* input = getInput();
char* saved_ptr = input;

// ...
// Change input
// ...    

// Deallocate memory using the original pointer
free(saved_ptr);
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is *most likely* these two lines:

```
for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)    //removes command and space and leaves parameters
    input++;
```

Here you *modify* the pointer, making you loose the original pointer that you should pass to `free`. You need to save the original pointer in a temporary variable, and pass that to `free`.

Answer (score 3):

You get an error because you are modifying the `input` pointer here:

```
for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)    //removes command and space and leaves parameters
    input++;
```

After this operation, `input` no longer points to the start of memory, allocated by `malloc`. Thus giving you the error. Instead, copy `input` to another pointer variable.

Also, consider doing allocation outside of `getInput()` since it is considered a good practice to allocate and free the memory in the same function, if possible.

Comment: Do I do the copy before or after the loop?

Comment: Before, to keep the original value